# (PySide2+anaconda) playing audio via QMediaPlayer: Warning: "Could not open audio device for playback."

Tags: qt, anaconda, gstreamer, pyside2, ubuntu-20.04

There are plenty of related questions already, but none of the existing informations covered/fixed this issue:

- Installed `PySide2` via anaconda on Ubuntu 20.04
- Followed basic steps and translating tutorial code to PySide2, to have a [QMediaPlayer](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtforpython-5.12/PySide2/QtMultimedia/QMediaPlayer.html) play a sound file

When loading the file via:

```
player.setMedia(url)
```

The warning

```
Warning: "Could not open audio device for playback."
```

gets printed on the terminal. No sound comes out although the URL is correct and other applications are able to play. **Crucially, loading the [Official Media Player Qt Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimediawidgets-player-example.html) via C++ QTCreator with the same qt5 version works.**

This last fact points at a faulty installation because of Python, anaconda, or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Diagnostic (skip below for solution):

Indeed, some investigation showed that the error was with the `gstreamer` lib, which probably wasn't able to pipe sound through the built-in `pulseaudio` server.

### To find out if your gstreamer works OK:

You can install gstreamer globally as described [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html?gi-language=c). Then, from a non-conda terminal, run the following:

```sh
# check that we're using the global/conda installation
which gst-launch-1.0
# play a test tone
gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! pulsesink
# play different audio formats
gst-play-1.0 ~/Desktop/test.wav
gst-play-1.0 ~/Desktop/test3.mp3
```

Which should work without any issues. Then, try the same from your conda environment. If the `which` command points to a different binary and you encounter issues, the solution below may work for you!

## Solution

The challenge now was to find out *what* was missing, and *which* version. After a lot of guessing and trying out combinations from the `conda` repositories, I found the following series of steps that lead from a fresh conda environment to a `PySide2` installation with working `gstreamer` and `QMediaPlayer.play()` functionality. It may work with other than Python 3.7, I'll be happy to hear if anyone gets any variation working as well!

```sh
# create env
conda create -y -c conda-forge -n qt37 python=3.7
conda activate qt37
# Gst-compatible installation
conda install -y -c conda-forge gst-plugins-base gst-plugins-good gstreamer
conda install -y -c conda-forge pulseaudio
conda install -y -c dtk-forge gst-plugins-good-pulseaudio
# Now the forge pyside2 is your friend
conda install -y -c conda-forge pyside2
```

Repeating the `gst` test above should now produce sounds and play files with the local installation. If that is the case, chances are that your `QMediaPlayer` works as well.

## To make sure...

Since the script is missing specific versions, here is the frozen `conda list` for the posterity. It may also help you modify an existing environment.

```sh
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       1_gnu    conda-forge
alsa-lib                  1.2.3                h516909a_0    conda-forge
attr                      2.4.48               h516909a_0    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2020.12.5            ha878542_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2020.12.5        py37h89c1867_1    conda-forge
dbus                      1.13.6               h48d8840_2    conda-forge
expat                     2.3.0                h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
fftw                      3.3.9           nompi_h74d3f13_101    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.13.1            hba837de_1005    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.4               h0708190_1    conda-forge
gettext                   0.19.8.1          h0b5b191_1005    conda-forge
glib                      2.68.1               h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
glib-tools                2.68.1               h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
gst-plugins-base          1.18.4               hf529b03_2    conda-forge
gst-plugins-good          1.18.4               h9f60fe5_2    conda-forge
gst-plugins-good-pulseaudio 1.18.4               h3fd9d12_0    dtk-forge
gstreamer                 1.18.4               h76c114f_2    conda-forge
icu                       68.1                 h58526e2_0    conda-forge
jack                      1.9.18            h295b1ef_1001    conda-forge
jpeg                      9d                   h36c2ea0_0    conda-forge
json-c                    0.15                 h98cffda_0    conda-forge
krb5                      1.17.2               h926e7f8_0    conda-forge
lame                      3.100             h7f98852_1001    conda-forge
ld_impl_linux-64          2.35.1               hea4e1c9_2    conda-forge
libcap                    2.48                 h7f98852_0    conda-forge
libclang                  11.1.0          default_ha53f305_0    conda-forge
libdb                     6.2.32               h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20191231         he28a2e2_2    conda-forge
libevent                  2.1.10               hcdb4288_3    conda-forge
libffi                    3.3                  h58526e2_2    conda-forge
libflac                   1.3.3                h9c3ff4c_1    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 9.3.0               h2828fa1_19    conda-forge
libgfortran-ng            9.3.0               hff62375_19    conda-forge
libgfortran5              9.3.0               hff62375_19    conda-forge
libglib                   2.68.1               h3e27bee_0    conda-forge
libgomp                   9.3.0               h2828fa1_19    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.16                 h516909a_0    conda-forge
libllvm11                 11.1.0               hf817b99_2    conda-forge
libogg                    1.3.4                h7f98852_1    conda-forge
libopus                   1.3.1                h7f98852_1    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               h21135ba_2    conda-forge
libpq                     13.2                 hfd2b0eb_2    conda-forge
libsndfile                1.0.31               h9c3ff4c_1    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              9.3.0               h6de172a_19    conda-forge
libtool                   2.4.6             h58526e2_1007    conda-forge
libuuid                   2.32.1            h7f98852_1000    conda-forge
libvorbis                 1.3.7                h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.13              h7f98852_1003    conda-forge
libxkbcommon              1.0.3                he3ba5ed_0    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.10               h72842e0_4    conda-forge
libxslt                   1.1.33               h15afd5d_2    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
mysql-common              8.0.23               ha770c72_2    conda-forge
mysql-libs                8.0.23               h935591d_2    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.2                  h58526e2_4    conda-forge
nspr                      4.30                 h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
nss                       3.64                 hb5efdd6_0    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1k               h7f98852_0    conda-forge
pcre                      8.44                 he1b5a44_0    conda-forge
pip                       21.1.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pthread-stubs             0.4               h36c2ea0_1001    conda-forge
pulseaudio                14.0                 hb166930_3    conda-forge
pyside2                   5.13.2           py37hfa98aef_4    conda-forge
python                    3.7.10          hffdb5ce_100_cpython    conda-forge
python_abi                3.7                     1_cp37m    conda-forge
qt                        5.12.9               hda022c4_4    conda-forge
readline                  8.1                  h46c0cb4_0    conda-forge
setuptools                49.6.0           py37h89c1867_3    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.35.5               h74cdb3f_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.10               h21135ba_1    conda-forge
wheel                     0.36.2             pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxau               1.0.9                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxdmcp             1.1.3                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.5                h516909a_1    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h516909a_1010    conda-forge
zstd                      1.4.9                ha95c52a_0    conda-forge
```

Hope this helps!
Andres